# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java:comp/env/jdbc/oracleInstance in java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

For some reason I can't connect to my database, So I am getting an error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java:comp/env/jdbc/oracleInstance` and I have a `DataUtility` class where I am connecting there with no problem. But in my method below, starting from `Class.forName` is where the error starts. Can anyone help me solve this issue. thanks!

Here is my code:

```
public void exportExcel() throws SQLException, Exception {

Class.forName("java:comp/env/jdbc/oracleInstance");
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "java:comp/env/jdbc/oracleInstance",
    "root",
    "root"
);


Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from myBean.va_v_vPay");
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("test db");

XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(1);
XSSFCell cell;
cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue("CLASS");
cell = row.createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue("GRADE");


int i = 2;

while (resultSet.next()) {
    row = spreadsheet.createRow(i);
    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getInt("Class"));
    cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("Grade"));

    i++;
}

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("all_file.xls"));
workbook.write(out);
out.close();
System.out.println("all_file.xls written successfully");
```

}

DataUtility:

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "dataUtility")
@ApplicationScoped
public final class DataUtility {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public DataUtility() throws NamingException {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(DataUtility.getDataSource());
    }

    private static DataSource getDataSource() throws NamingException {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds;

        try {
            ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/oracleInstance");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FATAL ERROR: " + e.toString());
            throw new NamingException(e.toString());
        }
        return ds;
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Class.forName("java:comp/env/jdbc/oracleInstance");` this type of call is usually to register a Java class as JDBC driver, but what you have provided is not a JDBC driver, but some sort of connection string.

Comment: can we do it with JDBC driver ?

Comment: or call my `DataUtility` because in the class I am doing the connection

Comment: I would look at the differences between the class that does work and this class and go from there. Specifically in the parts relating to getting the connection. If they work in the other class why are you doing them differently here? And for that matter, why is there more than one part of your project that deals with getting a database connection?

Comment: can I just call the `DataUtility` class inside my `exportExcel()` method?

Comment: Don't use: `Class.forName("name of driver class");`, this was required by JDBC 2.0, but is not needed (and discouraged) since JDBC 3.0, which was introduced in 2001 - 17 years ago

Comment: So, I just removed it...

Answer (score 2):

The string `java:comp/env/jdbc/oracleInstance` is a JNDI name. `Class.forName` expects the fully qualified name of a Java class (presumably a class that implements the JDBC driver interface).

If you're using Tomcat or some other application server, then you shouldn't need to use `Class.forName` yourself. Instead the container can be configured to provide you a DB connection pool that you can lookup using JNDI:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

If you're using a stand alone Java app, then you cannot use JNDI and you will need to do the driver look and DB connection yourself:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html

Looks like you're also using Spring, which has its own JDBC abstractions and utilities that can help you get a DB connection:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/